Water-soluble dye that won't stain acrylic
I'm in the middle of making a tank to model groundwater underneath a water storage. There will be water seeping down through sections of sand and clay, and I'm considering putting a blue dye in the water so it's more visible.
The front of the tank is a clear acrylic sheet, and the back is translucent polycarbonate. I want to make sure that any dye I put in won't stain the acrylic. If it won't stain the polycarbonate or the sand then that's a bonus.
So to save me buying and testing a heap, does anyone know of a suitable dye?

I use herbicide spray pattern tracking dyes, one brand name is "Lazer".  They are very water soluble, and although I can't speak to acrylic, it doesn't stain rock, sand, or human skin. The blue dye I use is very concentrated, and a little bit goes a long way.

My preference would be a fluorescent dye such as yellow sodium fluorescein. It is highly visible, non-toxic, water-soluble and should leave everything unstained. If you have bright white, bluish or UV light (e.g., direct sunlight or open sky), a very small fraction of a gram can stain hundreds of liters of water.

Update: we ended up using blue food colouring which worked very well and didn't stain the plastic or the sand. The trouble is most of the dye eventually got trapped by the clay, so we just had to top it up every now and then.
